# Connection refused error between containers when running a simple project with docker compose in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am following [this tutorial step by step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2019) exactly. Very simple one having .net core frontend and backend(webapi) projects.

But the communication between the frontend and the api does not happen. I always get

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: Connection refused
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: Connection refused
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)
```

Looks like I am missing something trivial here. But no matter what I tweak, I get the same communication exception. Driving me nuts now.

I have uploaded the full solution to [github here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/DockerComposeBug), in case if you want to take a look.

Its a 3.1 project and ensured as closed to the tutorial as possible. Even added a [bridge network](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/DockerComposeBug/blob/66eac6bd587ffa0cfb6cded9effde851587e0b79/WebFrontEnd/docker-compose.yml#L18) to the compose file after looking at some posts.

Here are some screen shots.

[image: Running the project in Visual Studio showing docker containers]

Finally here is the exception message.

[image: Connection Refused exception message]

**UPDATE**

So based on the suggestion of Exploding Kitten in the comment, I had removed the call to

```
// app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

in startup.cs of the Api project and things started working fine.

Or we can have a conditional as follows.

```
if (Configuration["DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER"] != "true")
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

We can detect if an app is running in the container using the env var `DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER`. Take a look at [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/detecting-that-a-net-core-app-is-running-in-a-docker-container-and-skippablefacts-in-xunit).

Comment: Try to disable HTTPS for your `mywebapi`, because it's trying to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (not sure whether it is supported by HttpClient or not), but your frontend will not trust your self-signed certificate anyway.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Commenting out app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in the WEB API project made the difference finally. It was mentioned in the tutorial. But I was only doing it in the front end project and not in the api project.